# C#: Can't I use an anonymous delegate in ThreadStart?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Can't I have an anonymous delegate declaration, something similar to the following:

```
    ThreadStart starter = delegate() { go(); };
            ...

    static void go()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Nice Work");
    }

   // (or)

   ThreadStart starter=delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Hello");}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks ok.  What problem are you having, exactly?

Comment: Are anonymous delegates used anywhere else in the code? Me wonders if this code is not targeting .NET Framework v1.x...

Comment: Why do you think it is not possible? I get this code to work. The only problem is that you try to manipulate the user interface (Console.Writeline) from a non UI thread. That is not allowed.

Comment: @Dabblernl All members of the Console class are thread safe.

Comment: @Dabblernl Calling Console.WriteLine() is perfectly legal from a different thread than the one running the entry-point. Also, per paper1337's question, what version of the Framework are you targetting?

Comment: I missed semicolon somewhere.Now it is working.Thanks everybody.

Comment: sorry, I should have tested before writing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What error do you get?  Missing semicolon?  This compiles for me.

```
    static void go()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nice Work");
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadStart starter1 = delegate() { go(); };

        ThreadStart starter2 = delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Hello");};

        ThreadStart starter3 = () =>  Console.WriteLine("Hello");

    }
```

Comment: can not convert anaonymous method to type ThreadStart. I m using ASp.NET 3.5 and C# 3.0. Just compiling the same example provided by you.

Comment: have you included `using System.Threading`  ?  Is there any other text in that error message?

Comment: As you said  i missed semicolon,now it is fine.Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You can skip the ThreadStart. This should work.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
});
```

Comment: Got a feeling that we're dealing with an older .net version here. In that case, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Whats the actual question?

By the way, you're missing a semicolon at the end of your second example:

```
ThreadStart starter=delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Hello");}
```

should be:

```
ThreadStart starter = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); };
```

Though the spacing I added is personal choice.